# Conflict between nexmo and google sign in

Tags: android, gradle, google-signin, conflict, vonage

My app level `build.gradle` has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'     
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'        
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'       
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'       
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'     
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.nexmo:verify:4.0.0'
}
```

The problem I am having is that the Application crashes once I run it. Now I understand why it's crashing, its because I have that red curly line in `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'`which says something like `all gms/firebase must use the same exact version` .
 I ran `./gradlew app:dependencies`. I think what caused the problem is nexmo is using google firebase messaging 9.8.0 and we have that sign in from google which is 11.8.0. So I commented the Nexmo dependency and sure enough the red curly line in google auth dependency is gone. But I need the nexmo verify.
I also tried changing the google auth dependency version to 9.8.0 to see if that works, but it seems that all the classes for Google Sign in are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nexmo library](https://github.com/Nexmo/verify-android-sdk/blob/verify4.0.0/verifySDK/build.gradle) seems to use very old dependencies (last commit was 1 year ago)

Add in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I be worried that Nexmo is using old dependencies? My app needs a lot of SMS and verification features. Should I switch to other service providers like Twillio or Sinch?.. What do you recommend